# Python rearranging a list into a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following code:

def ex1 ():

```
b= input("Please enter a file name to be opened: ")
a = (b+".txt")

c =[]

def employee(lanme,oname,num,title,salary):
    c.append(employee)

def readfile(a):
    try:
        data =[]
        check = open(a, 'r')
        line =check.readlines()
        for items in line:
            breakup= items.split()
            data.append(breakup)
    except IOError as e :
        print("Failed to open", fileName)




readfile(a)
```

ex1()

What it does is basically reads a text file with an employee information in it. 
For example:
The format the text file comes in is: (num, salary, position, oname, lname)

```
15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John , 
14522 24500 Team Leader Baker George ,
22422 24352 Crew member house bob
```

I need to take the information from the text file and re arrange it into the format that is in def employee function. 
Which is (lanme,oname,num,title,salary) from the original which comes as (num, salary, position, oname, lname).

I am aware of ways of doing this but it needs to be stored as a tuple and can be accessed seperately or as a whole item.

I apologize if this question seems a poorly explained but I tried my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for items in data:
  id, salary, title, lastname, firstname = items
  employee(lastna,e, firstname, id, title, salary)
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick feedback however after I have implemented the loop and made sure the variables are correct I have a valuerror where it says it is trying to unpack too many things. It expects 5 but there is 5. I have also edited my employee function in line with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Alex said, your `employee` function is certainly not doing what you want it to. Right now it is appending references to itself to `c`, so `c` will be a list like `[<employee function>, <employee function>, ...]`
If you want an employee represented by a tuple, have the function return the tuple.

```
def employee(lanme, oname, num,title,salary):
    return (lanme, oname, num, title, salary)
```

EDIT:

To explain Alex's answer, we unpack the list into variables and make a new tuple from the unpacked list. Here's a simple example

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b, c, d, e = mylist # a=0, b=1, ...
mytuple = (e, d, c, b, a) # mytuple = (4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

With these changes, your script would look like

```
b = input("Please enter a file name to be opened: ")
a = b + '.txt'

def employee(lname, oname, num, title, salary):
    return (lname, oname, num, title, salary)

def readfile(a):

    # Instead of the try/except block
    # you can use a with statement
    with open(a, 'r') as check:
        data = []

        # You can also skip the readlines()
        # and iterate over the file directly
        for items in check:

            # This is unpacking, see the note above
            # Also, based on your example file **this won't work**, see below note
            num, salary, position, oname, lname = items.split()
            newemployee = employee(lname, oname, num, title, salary)
            data.append(newemployee)
    return data

myemployees = readfile(a)
```

Finally, `items.split()` is also probably not what you want.
If you have the line `15674 24000 Manager Gregory the 1st John ,`, then using `split` will give you `['15674', '24000', 'Manager', 'Gregory', 'the', '1st', 'John' ',']` while the list you want is `['15674', '24000', 'Manager', 'Gregory the 1st', 'John'].

Getting that list depends on your file structure, which seems inconsistent making it difficult. Fields separated by spaces, some fields are multiple words, sometimes trailing commas.

Comment: Ive followed the feedback but i'm new to python and i'm not sure how to implement/understand what parts of the replies do.